# lithium insert entity array into model object property

Tags: php, lithium

The following coding sample doesn't work.

```
$joiner = new Entity();
$joiner->name = $post['name'];
$joiner->address = $post['address'];
$meeting = Meeting::first($_id);
$meeting->joiner[] = $joiner;
$meeting->save();
```

I hope each time when the form posted success. a new joiner entity should be pushed into the 'joiner' property of meeting object.

How to correct it ? and thanks for all help.

**updated**

now I have changed it like this .it works fine but still not very good yet.

```
$joiner = new Entity();
$joiner->name = $post['name'];
$joiner->address = $post['address'];
$meeting = Meeting::first($_id);

if(empty($meeting->joiner)){
    $joiners = array($joiner);
}
else{
    $joiners = array();
    foreach($meeting->joiner as $one){
        $joiners[] = $one;
    }
    $joiners[] = $joiner;
}

$meeting->joiner = $joiners;
$meeting->save();
```